# MOS-Capacitor Work function calculation. Units don't match. What am I missing?

Tags: capacitance, semiconductor-physics, units

I am currently doing some lab work and I am stuck at a single equation that doesn't make any sense to me. I am given the following formula for the work function of Silicon:

$$\Phi_{Si}=\chi_{Si}+\frac{E_g}{2q}+\Phi_B$$

where $q$ is the charge of an electron, $\chi_{Si}=4,05 eV$ the Electron affinity of Silicon, $E_g=1,1,24 eV$ the band gap of Silicon and $\Phi_B=0,275 V$ the bulk potential of Silicon.

I have checked this equation across multiple sites (for example [here](https://ecee.colorado.edu/%7Ebart/book/book/chapter6/ch6_3.htm))and across multiple lectures I have had. However, **the units just don't make any sense**.

$$\Phi_{Si}=\text{Units of energy}+\frac{\text{Units of energy}}{\text{Coulomb}}+\frac{\text{Units of energy}}{\text{Coulomb}}$$

I think I am slowly going insane. What am I missing here?

Comment: Presumably the "affinity" $\chi_{\rm Si}$ should also be in Volts. Your linked souce says that the work function $\Phi$ has units of volts and $E/q$ has units of Volts.  I agree that affinity is usually an energy per mole, and so usually boils down to an *energy* per particle.  You are right to be confused!

Comment: @mikestone Thanks for the answer. I just browsed a bit in Neaman's "Semiconductor physics and devices 4th ed." and on page 382 he has a very similar formula EXCEPT he has $\chi'$ and defines it as the "modified electron affinity" measured in Volts. He doesn't really go into detail why his electron affinity suddenly has units Volts instead of eV.

Comment: There is only one electron involved in the procees described by the work-function,  so Volts, electron-Volts and 4.05 V and 4.05eV don't need any numerical conversion.... just laziness I expect. Engineers can be casual. Window air-conditions are rated in "BtU," butthe actual units are BtU/hr.